# How to include a call to ncat to a bash script?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

I need to flush a memcached instance from a bash script, I found the following command which do the job:

```
echo 'flush_all' | ncat localhost 11211
```

But my problem is that the script doesn't continue next command, it stops with `ncat`'s response:

[image]

If I manually send the command on my console I need to do a `CTRL+C` to kill the process.

I think it's a normal behaviour of `echo` or `ncat` command, but I don't know to bypass it... Do you know how to workaround it?

Answer (score 1):

Have you attempted to use some of the timing options of `ncat`? Here's the relevant event excerpt from `man ncat(1)`.

> TIMING OPTIONS
>
> ```
>   These options accept a time parameter. This is specified in seconds by
>   default, though you can append ms, s, m, or h to the value to specify
>   milliseconds, seconds, minutes, or hours.
>
>   -d time, --delay time (Specify line delay) .
>       Set the delay interval for lines sent. This effectively limits the
>       number of lines that Ncat will send in the specified period. This
>       may be useful for low-bandwidth sites, or have other uses such as
>       coping with annoying iptables --limit options.
>
>   -i time, --idle-timeout time (Specify idle timeout) .
>       Set a fixed timeout for idle connections. If the idle timeout is
>       reached, the connection is terminated.
>
>   -w time, --wait time (Specify connect timeout) .
>       Set a fixed timeout for connection attempts.
> ```

So in your situation you would run `echo 'flush_all' | ncat -i 10s localhost 11211`.

Comment: Good idea, I looked on `ncat`'s options, and I found `--send-only` which do the job